Nuxt 3 Unit Test with Vitest
my senior ask me to write unit test in Nuxt 3 project and gave me this config
vitest.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  test: {
    environment: 'happy-dom',
    coverage: {
      reportsDirectory: './coverage',
      provider: 'v8',
      reporter: ['html'],
      include: [
        '**/components/**',
        '**/pages/**',
      ],
    },
  },
})

but, when i'm test this component
components/SampleComponent.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Drawer } from '~/components/ui/drawer'

const sayHello = computed(() => {
  return (name) => {
    return `Hello ${name}`
  }
})
const viewport = useViewport()
</script>

<template>
  <main v-if="viewport.isGreaterOrEquals('lg')">
    <Drawer>
      <h1>{{ sayHello('John Doe') }}</h1>
    </Drawer>
  </main>
</template>

and my test is this
SampleComponent.spec.ts
import { describe, expect, it } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import SampleComponent from './SampleComponent.vue'

describe('sampleComponent', () => {
  it('renders Drawer component when viewport is large', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(SampleComponent, {
      global: {
        components: {
          Drawer: {
            template: '<div><slot /></div>',
          },
        },
      },
    })
    expect(wrapper.find('div').exists()).toBe(true)
  })
})

i got error
Error: Failed to resolve import "~/components/ui/drawer" from "components/SampleComponent.vue". Does the file exist?

but when i change from this
import { Drawer } from '~/components/ui/drawer'

to this
import { Drawer } from './ui/drawer'

i got this error
ReferenceError: computed is not defined

i think the vitest config is wrong, what should i do?
is nuxt unit test only for components/ and can't test for pages/ ?

"give me this config" - this is wrong direction, you'd need to configure a lot of things from scratch to match a config that nuxt app has. You already met ~ alias and unplugin autoimports, they don't exist in vanilla vue setup that your config contains. I'd suggest to start with reading the fine manual https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/testing#unit-testing
